# Is there a loop function for editing google sheet cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

This is my first time in stack, and I've googled heaps on solutions.  Hoping there is something simple I am missing to create a loop.

I've tried recording a simple macro to right click a cell, select edit, and select apply, however the macro is recording the value of the cell, which means it is overriding cell values when it is run.  Is there a simple script to stop this?

I'm used to excel, but trying to find a solution in sheets, so wondering if a loop will be appropriate.  Set value needs to be a variable value; any thoughts on how to fix it?

MACRO CODE:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-2, -1).activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setShowHyperlink(true);

//the issue is in this line following .setValue
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(**'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uha5arh1obgy3bu/AAAr3pP5ozoVL7BMPtqe22G_a/LWK---Spiritual-healing-crystal-bracelets--celebrate-sisterhood-friendship.jpg?dl=0'**);
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(3, 0).activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setShowHyperlink(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> I've tried recording a simple macro to right click a cell, select edit, and select apply, however the macro is recording the value of the cell, which means it is overriding cell values when it is run. Is there a simple script to stop this?

Just remove

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(**'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uha5arh1obgy3bu/AAAr3pP5ozoVL7BMPtqe22G_a/LWK---Spiritual-healing-crystal-bracelets--celebrate-sisterhood-friendship.jpg?dl=0'**);
```

Regarding the "loop" part, there area a lot of ways of doing loops i.e. you could use a [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)